# random_device vs default_random_engine

Tags: c++, c++11, random

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> coll{1, 2, 3, 4};
    shuffle(coll.begin(), coll.end(), random_device{});

    default_random_engine dre{random_device{}()};
    shuffle(coll.begin(), coll.end(), dre);
}
```

Question 1: What's the difference between

`shuffle(coll.begin(), coll.end(), random_device{});`

and

`shuffle(coll.begin(), coll.end(), dre);`?

Question 2: Which is better?

Comment: `default_random_engine` is implementation-defined - this means you need to read your platform documentation to see what generator you are getting.  There are other standard specified generators see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random  Advice is don't use `default_random_engine` unless you want platform specific behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Question 1: What's the difference between...

`std::random_device` conceptually produces true random numbers. Some implementations will stall if you exhaust the system's source of entropy so this version may not perform as well.

`std::default_random_engine` is a pseudo-random engine. Once seeded, with an random number it would be extremely difficult (but not impossible) to predict the next number.

There is another subtle difference. `std::random_device::operator()` will throw an exception if it fails to come up with a random number.

> Question 2: Which is better?

It depends. For most cases, you probably want the performance and temporal-determinism of the pseudorandom engine seeded with a random number, so that would be the second option.

Comment: One thing that is sort of annoying is that although the docs say that `std::random_device` is supposed to be true random numbers, when I looked in my libc++ headers, its actually `/dev/urandom` and not `/dev/random`, so its technically pseudorandom also and probably not blocking. But on windows I guess it's some crypto api? I feel like `std::random_device` is not that well specified right now. Also is bad that there is no exception-free interface imo. My tendency recently is to go around it and use `/dev/random` directly, unless I know I'm on windows and then use `random_device`.

Comment: @ChrisBeck At least on Linux, /dev/urandom is functionally the same as /dev/random except that the latter does not block for secure numbers if the entropy pool runs out and uses a PRNG instead. The entropy pool is huge, so any exploit code would need to exhaust the pool and also predict when it's out and generating more.

Answer (score 4):

Both `random_device` and `default_random_engine` are implementation defined. `random_device` should provide a nondeterministic source of randomness if available, but it may also be a prng in some implementations. Use random_device if you want unpredictable random numbers (most machines nowadays have hardware entropy sources). If you want pseudo random numbers you'd probably use one of the specific algorithms, like the `mersenne_twister_engine`.

I guess `default_random_engine` is what you'd use if you don't care about the particulars of how you get your random numbers. I'd suspect it'd just use `rand` under the hood or a `linear_congruential_engine` most of the time.

I don't think the question "which is better" can be answered objectively. It depends on what you're trying to do with your random numbers. If they're supposed to be random sources for some cryptographic process, I suspect `default_random_engine` is a terrible choice, although I'm not a security expert, so I'm not sure if even `random_device` is good enough.